# Links in PHP echo

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

You may have seen from my previous questions, I'm brand new to PHP (and coding) and I'm stuck with this.

I've created this code (try not to cringe):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `username`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE `approved` = '0' ORDER BY `username`;");

    echo "<table>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<tr><td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td> | </td><td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . " </td><td> | </td><td><a href=\"approve_user.php?phpuser_id=$row['user_id']\"><font color=\"green\">Approve</font></a> | </td><td><a href=\"deny_user.php?user_id=$row['user_id']\"><font color=\"red\">Delete</font></a></td>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

It connects to the database in another file, returns all of the results successfully etc. However, the problems come when I try adding the 'Approve' and 'Delete' links. I want the approve link to go to `approve_user.php?user_id=$row['user_id']` and I want the delete link to go to `deny_user.php?user_id=$row['user_id']`.

I'm getting the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\liste\approve.php on line 22
```

Line 22 is the echo in the while loop. I know I've messed up big time on that line somewhere, but for the life of me I can't figure out where. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You should put each `<td>...</td>` on its own line so you can tell where the error is.

Comment: I don't see any protection here such as `addslashes` / `stripslashes` or `htmlentities`.  It's very possible a value in your data is conflicting with PHP.

Comment: Your PARAMS are not correct the way I understand it. Change this approve_user.php?phpuser_id=$row['user_id'] to this approve_user.php?user_id=$row['user_id'] then get user_id from the other file

Comment: As I have warned you in my comment, you have `</tr>` missng in your code. This is not related to your question, but is important anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is to concatenate your variables:

```
echo "<tr><td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td> | </td><td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . " </td><td> | </td><td><a href=\"approve_user.php?phpuser_id=" . $row['user_id'] . "\"><font color=\"green\">Approve</font></a> | </td><td><a href=\"deny_user.php?user_id=" . $row['user_id'] . "\"><font color=\"red\">Delete</font></a></td>";
```

However, the code could benefit from making it more readable or using a template system, or at least consider separating the logic and presentation.

---

Side note: The `mysql_*` library is deprecated, it is recommended to upgrade to PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: The variables can be kept in the string.

Comment: @TomášZato IMO the `{}` syntax with associative arrays is less readable and less clean than concatenation or other methods.

Comment: @MrCode That's your opinion. I find concatenation overly verbose and error-prone to type. My personal preference is `sprintf()`.

Comment: @MrCode This depends on what you call *clean*. If your code highliter doesn't support this syntax, it is less readable. But otherwise, it saves you 2 quotes per variable and makes your file very nice readable. So simply, this is just a **matter of opinion**. Maybe we can discuss the code interpretation speed.

Comment: @Barmar and Tomas, as I said IMO it's less clean but I would not go with either method personally, I would use a template, even if it's just a basic no framework PHP template, anything is better than echoing raw HTML like that.

Comment: Thanks for this, and thank you for the advice MrCode! I'll choose this as accepted answer, but thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You must put {} over array variables in PHP strings:

```
$text = "Variable = {$_GET["user_input"]}\nSimple variable = $var";
```

Means your code should look like (I added newlines to make code better readable):

```
echo "<tr><td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td> | </td>\n";
echo "<td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . " </td><td> | </td><td><a href=\"approve_user.php?phpuser_id={$row['user_id']}\"><font color=\"green\">Approve</font></a> | </td>\n";
echo "<td><a href=\"deny_user.php?user_id={$row['user_id']}\"><font color=\"red\">Delete</font></a></td></tr>\n\n";
```

You also had **missing `</tr>`**. I fixed that above.

Answer (score 0):

When you're interpolating array elements into a string, there are two ways to do it:

```
$string = "blah blah $array[key] blah blah";
```

or:

```
$string = "blah blah {$array['key']} blah blah";
```

If you don't surround the array variable with `{}`, you must leave out the quotes around the key. The key is automatically assumed to be a literal string.

**Note**: This assumption is *only* done in string interpolation. You can't write:

$foo = $array[key];

In this case, `key` is interpreted as the name of a constant, not a literal string.

The second format is more general, because you can put other expressions in the key. It can also be used with object references.

Other ways to do it are with concatenation:

```
$string = "blah blah " . $array['key'] . " blah blah";
```

or `sprintf()`:

```
$string = sprintf("blah blah %s blah blah", $array['key']);
```

Comment: The firs way is wrong and produces **undefined constant notice**.

Comment: @TomášZato That's only true outside of string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this :

```
 <?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `username`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE `approved` =  '0' ORDER BY `username`;");

  echo "<table>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $userID = $row['user_id'];
        echo "<tr><td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($username) . "</td><td> | </td><td align=center>" . htmlspecialchars($email) . " </td><td> | </td><td><a href=\"approve_user.php?phpuser_id=$userID\"><font color=\"green\">Approve</font></a> | </td><td><a href=\"deny_user.php?user_id=$userID\"><font color=\"red\">Delete</font></a></td>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Comment: Surelly the worst idea. I won't downvote only because it would work, so its an answer.